# ArrayIndex Out OfBound Error in swing with java codeing

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have six entries in my database/`Jtable`. When I click on `JTable` I
 display all selected data in text field except Date(dob). It shows me an
 error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 >= 5

```
table = new JTable();
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Write your code here 
        tabmod = table.getModel();
        int SelectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
        txtid.setText(tabmod.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
        txtname.setText(tabmod.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
        txtlname.setText(tabmod.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 2).toString());
        String gender =tabmod.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 3).toString();
        if(gender.equals("male")){
            rdbtnmale.setSelected(true);
        }else{
            rdbtnfemale.setSelected(true);
        }
        String dob = tabmod.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 4).toString();
        txtage.setText(tabmod.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 5).toString());//Here throw an error 5>=5 ArrayIndexOutOfBound
        //This line print the value eg id
        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click event active");

    }
});
tab_disp_user.setViewportView(table);
```

Comment: How is your table model defined/initialized? Please add code for it

Comment: JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
  scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    String quer = "select * from userreg";
    try {
     PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(quer);
     ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
     table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
   }
  });
  scrollPane.setBounds(387, 48, 537, 330);
  frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

Comment: public class UserModel {
 
 private int id;
 private String name,lname,gender;
 private int age;
 private Date dob;

Comment: Njena please edit your question instead of commenting with code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your table has only five columns you are trying to get 6th column value for the selected row. Generally column index is counted (0 to n-1 ) where 0 is first column index and n-1 is nth column.